# how do I get my literal to be a num in haskell

Tags: haskell

So I'm quite the newb in haskell and questions abound. I've been reading through a couple books and trying to do a few things on my own, can someone please explain to me why this is complaining that the literal doesn't implement eq, I understand why eq is necessary- but I don't understand why this is seen as a literal rather than a num or how I change that.

```
generateListOfRandoms :: a -> b -> c -> d -> [(d, (a, b))]
generateListOfRandoms _ _ 0 _ = []
generateListOfRandoms rangeStart rangeEnd numberOfRandoms randGenerator =
    (randGenerator, (rangeStart,rangeEnd))  : generateListOfRandoms rangeStart rangeEnd (numberOfRandoms-1) randGenerator
```

I'm sure my function is going to fail in other ways when I try giving it an IO function as some of you could guess, but I'm confused right now why I get this error:

```
src\Main.hs:23:27:
    No instance for (Eq c)
      arising from the literal `0'
    In the pattern: 0
    In an equation for `generateListOfRandoms':
        generateListOfRandoms _ _ 0 _ = []
```

Comment: I also tried using a guard instead and it just complained that the literal 0 didn't implement Eq just the same

Comment: Your type signature says that the third argument can be of any type, but surely you want to restrict it only for numeric types (otherwise you can't use `0` as a pattern). In Haskell, you'd express that as `(Num c) => a -> b -> c -> ...`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use a numeric literal, the type of the corresponding argument must belong to the `Num` class. Also, since you are pattern-matching against a numeric literal, you need the type to belong to the `Eq` class. You have to add these constraints to your type signature,

```
generateListOfRandoms :: (Num c, Eq c) => a -> b -> c -> d -> [(d, (a, b))]
```

If you're not using GHC-7.4, the `Eq` constraint is implied by the `Num` constraint, that has recently been changed, so now you have to state both explicitly if you use both.

Comment: Thanks! I tried both of these constraints before but not together. This is why it was missing.

Comment: `Num` is a subclass of `Eq`, so just `Num c => ...` is sufficient

Comment: @newacct `Num` is no longer a subclass of `Eq` in ghc 7.4, as Daniel points out.